# How to reference another value within the same appsettings.json file?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog, appsettings

I need database connection string in two places in appsettings.json.

Is it possible to introduce common variable or json-path related references into json file to avoid potencial problems?

It would be lovely to have it without touching c# code.

```
{
...
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Host=localhost;Database=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"
  },
  "Nlog": {
    "targets": {
      "database": {
        "type": "Database",
        "dbProvider": "Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql",
        "connectionString": "Host=localhost;Database=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres",
...
      }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NLog has the ability to lookup values in the appsettings.json. You can do it like this with `${configsetting}`:

```
{
...
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Host=localhost;Database=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"
  },
  "Nlog": {
    "targets": {
      "database": {
        "type": "Database",
        "dbProvider": "Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql",
        "connectionString": "${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.Default}",
...
      }
    }
...
}
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Comment: It works! Whats a pity that you cannot use it in general appsettings file

Answer (score 5):

I've created a nuget package exactly for this! Check it out here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TemplateFormattedConfiguration/

In your example you should do this:

```
{
...
    "ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "Host=localhost;Database=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"
  },
  "Nlog": {
    "targets": {
      "database": {
        "type": "Database",
        "dbProvider": "Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql",
        "connectionString": "{ConnectionStrings:Default}",
...
      }
    }
...
}
```

And in your Startup.cs (or Program.cs) you'll add this:

```
        configuration.EnableTemplatedConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no support for this. Two things, though:

1. While the data being provided in each case is the same, the two things are *not* the same. It's not a duplication when both just happen to be using the same data source, as that may just as well not be the case.
2. There's nothing magical about the `ConnectionStrings` section, except that it allows you to use the `GetConnectionString` sugar. You could just as well do something like:

   ```
   services.AddDbContext(o =>
       o.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Nlog:targets:database:connectionString"]));
   ```

   Whether or not that's appropriate is a separate discussion. The point is that you don't *have* to have the value multiple times, if you're just dead set against it.